# Splitting rows based on intersecting dates. Details below

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have some data on Hadoop which looks like this:

```
--Id---------Start_Ts--------------End_Ts--+  
  1 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/04/2012  
  2 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/06/2012  
  3 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/05/2012  
  4 ----|---03/04/2013----|------04/04/2017
```

I now wish to split my rows in a way that there's no time overlap between end_ts of one row and start_ts of another row. I want a final set to look like:

```
--Id---------Start_Ts--------------End_Ts--+  
1 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/04/2012  
2 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/04/2012  
2 ----|---01/04/2012----|------01/05/2012  
2 ----|---01/05/2012----|------01/06/2012  
3 ----|---01/01/2012----|------01/04/2012  
3 ----|---01/04/2012----|------01/05/2012  
4 ----|---03/04/2013----|------04/04/2017
```

---

What is the best way to do this in Spark or Hive? What method best suited for something like this

Comment: how do you calculate Start_Ts and End_Ts new values ?

Comment: bit tricky to explain. so looking at id 2's start and end time stamps, we can see that id 1 and 3 are active at that time. so i need to split id 2 into three parts using the time stamps of those two rows. i really don't know how to explain without the table which i have already posted.. sorry!